# Initilalising an array with a sequence in Fortran

Tags: arrays, fortran, translation

I am currently working on translating some legacy fortran code and I am having a hard time understanding a particular line in the code. The compiler also seems to find this line weird and throws out an error. From what I understand it is trying to initialize an array by sequencing 1 to 9 by increments of 1 and filling up the array matrix with this sequence in column major form.

```
program arrayProg

  integer :: matrix(3,3), i , j !two dimensional real array

  matrix = reshape((/1:9:1/), (/3,3/))

end program arrayProg
```

Is this syntax acceptable in fortran? (It has to be because it comes from the legacy code)
Am I misunderstanding what the line does?

Comment: What kind of error did the compiler find? Which compiler? Please see [ask] and [mcve], you should always give all the information you have. The erro mesage us isually extremely important.  The syntax is not correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax is incorrect and such code cannot be compiled by a Fortran compiler, unless it implements some non-standard extension.

Intel Fortran accepts this:

```
 A colon-separated triplet (instead of an implied-DO loop) to specify a range of values and a stride; for example, the following two array constructors are equivalent:
1       INTEGER D(3)
2       D = (/1:5:2/)              ! Triplet form - also [1:5:2]
3       D = (/(I, I=1, 5, 2)/)     ! implied-DO loop form
```

from [Development Reference Guides:Array Constructors](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/fortran-compiler-oneapi-dev-guide-and-reference/top/language-reference/data-types-constants-and-variables/variables-1/arrays/array-constructors.html)

(note: The links to Intel Documentation change frequently, if the link is dead, please notify me in the comment and try searching for "triplet form" and "array constructors")

To generate a sequence in a standard way one uses an implied do loop like

```
 (/ (i, i=1,9) /)
```

the reshape then just changes the 1D array into a 2D one in column major order as you guessed.

Comment: BTW, every time someone recommends to use some non-standard extension, especially ugly stuff like the DEC extensions, in new code, think about situations like this. Someone will inherit the code, will get some different compiler and will be screwed or at least confused and it will be PIA to rewrite the code to a standard form. You cannot say "It is portable because I always use Intel, that is nonsense".

Comment: Agreed, though in this case it's really irritating that modern Fortran has a perfectly usable syntax for integer sequence generation that can only be used on array indices. It's natural to try to use this approach for creating integer sequences only to find one is forced to use an implied-DO loop to stay within the language standard (translation: I've been bitten by this.) This is why I recommend building code under multiple compilers even if you don't intend to use the result; you get quick notification of non-standard extensions.

Comment: That's now a broken link.  Possibly [this one](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/fortran-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference/top/language-reference/data-types-constants-and-variables/variables-1/arrays/array-constructors.html) instead.